# Identify a bar of interest on an OHLC chart on the graph itself

Tags: r, xts

I have calculations that identify bar location of events; my calculation output is the number of a bar within my time series or its index (I can work with either).  The issue I have is that when I have more than 50 bars on the chart I have to count the bars to identify the bar of interest.

Is there a way to put some kind of an "indicator" on the chart itself for the bars of interest based on the calculation I have?
Say my program indicated bar 3 is a bar of interest.  Are there any tricks that would help in identifying that bar graphically on the chart with an arrow or a dot or anything really to avoid having to count the bars.  I realize the time is usually on the x axes, but when the chart has many bars you can't read the time and date off the chart, and even if you did its hard to be sure they are aligned properly.

I provided an OHLC AAPL data for 5 minute bars bellow as a dput():
would like to be able to tell R "when you chart my data please identify bar  #3 on the chart"
I usually use chartSeries() of the quantmod package to create my charts, but I am open to using other functions.

```
dput(AAPL)
structure(c(266, 265.95, 265.93, 265.89, 265.91, 266, 266, 265.96, 
265.97, 265.98, 265.93, 265.9, 265.84, 265.86, 265.8625, 265.97, 
265.96, 265.89, 265.875, 265.98), .Dim = c(5L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
NULL, c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close")), index = structure(c(1299962039, 
1299962098, 1299962157, 1299962219, 1299962278), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "", .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", class = c("xts", "zoo"))

chartSeries(AAPL) would create an OHLC bar chart with 5 bars.
```

Comment: on what chart? I don't see any code to create a chart.

Comment: I didn't provide one because there are many functions to chart with. I use chartSeries(AAPL)

Comment: yeah, and different types of charting functions will require a different solution to your problem.  So, what plotting/charting framework are you dealing with?

Comment: All the more reason to provide one. What if someone provides a solution with a function you don't want to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AAPL <- structure(c(266, 265.95, 265.93, 265.89, 265.91, 266, 266, 265.96, 
265.97, 265.98, 265.93, 265.9, 265.84, 265.86, 265.8625, 265.97, 
265.96, 265.89, 265.875, 265.98), .Dim = c(5L, 4L),
.Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close")),
index = structure(c(1299962039, 1299962098, 1299962157, 1299962219, 1299962278),
  tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")),
tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "",
.indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", class = c("xts", "zoo"))
chartSeries(AAPL)
addLines(v=3)
addPoints(3, Cl(AAPL)[3])
```

Comment: I should have asked this question a year ago, you have no idea how much time I spent counting bars to check results.  I really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: @user2004820 here's a function that adds a line (really shading) based on indexes: https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/qmao/R/addVLine.R?view=markup&root=twsinstrument  (see the examples section right above the function definition)